# PHP Array check the count of same values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having troubles comparing two arrays with `array_inersect()`, tried lot of suggestion from SO but none worked. So here is my problem:

I have two arrays:

```
$base_array = array(2,2,2,1);

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

And another one `$risks` that prints like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 6
)
```

What I want is to see if the **same number and type of values** from `$base_array` fits into `$risks` array. Right now it should return false cause I only have two occurences of number 2 and base array has 3. But if I set `$base_array` to:

```
$base_array = array(2,2,1);
```

This should return true.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I can't make any code to give me what I need, everything I tried was array_intersect and array_diff but didn't work. Always returning true cause 2 exists in both but no same occurence.

Comment: Is it supposed to return true when there are two 2's in `$base_array`? i.e we are checking if there are two 2's and one 1, right?

Comment: Add the attempts with `array_intersect` and `array_diff` in your question, and in which sense they didn't work. Then we can/will help.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator exatcly. This is just an example, but yes in this case it should return false cause there are three 2's in `$base_array` but if we set `$base_array = array(2,2,1);` it should return True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be counting occurrence of each number then manually comparing them. For this you need two array to keep the occurrence count.

```
$base_array_count = [];
$risks_count = [];
```

In your case `$base_array_count` will look like

```
$base_array_count[1] = 1
$base_array_count[2] = 2
```

And the `$risks_array_count` will look like

```
$risks_count[1] = 1
$risks_count[2] = 2
$risks_count[3] = 1
$risks_count[4] = 1
$risks_count[6] = 1
$risks_count[8] = 1
```

Now loop through `$base_array` and check if each numbers `$base_array_count` value is same as in `$risks_array_count`

Complete code after edit:

```
$base_array = array(1,2,2,7);
$risks_array = array(2,3,4,5,6,7);

$base_array_count = array();
$risks_array_count = [];

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($base_array); $i++){
    if( !isset($base_array_count[$base_array[$i]] ))
        $base_array_count[$base_array[$i]] = 0;
    $base_array_count[$base_array[$i]]++;
}

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($risks_array); $i++){
    if( !isset($risks_array_count[$risks_array[$i]] ))
        $risks_array_count[$risks_array[$i]] = 0;
    $risks_array_count[$risks_array[$i]]++;
}

$same = true;

if (sizeof($base_array) <= sizeof($risks_array)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($base_array); $i++) {
        if(!isset($risks_array_count[$base_array[$i]]) || $base_array_count[$base_array[$i]] != $risks_array_count[$base_array[$i]]){
            $same = false;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $same = false;
}
if($same)
    echo "TRUE";
else
    echo "FALSE";
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I tried with `array_diff` but it didn't worked very well. Can you please explain how should I loop for each `$base_array_count` and compare?

Comment: @rgomez Added the complete code, check if it solves your problem.

Comment: almost perfect and sorry for being such meticulous but this will be very important on my code. It works pefectly even tried adding other numbers into base_array like 8 or 4 (`$base_array = array(1,2,2,4,8);`) and of course If I set 2,2,2 it returns false. But the problem comes if I set for instance `$base_array = array(1,2,2,7);` I get `Undefined offset: 7`

Comment: @ Risul Islam, after last change according to your edit the `Undefined offset` Notice goes away but setting `$base_array = array(1,2,2,7);` should return False and returns True.

Comment: @rgomez It shows me False. I don't know why it shows you True. Did you update your code properly? I am changing complete code according to edit try this.

Comment: Yes, I copied it exactly now. But please try this `$base_array = array(1,2,2,7); $risks_array = array(1,2,2,3,4,5,6);` it should return False cause number 7 doesn't even exist on the risks_array but it returns True. Every other scheme is working properly, the only problem there is a number on the base_array that doesn't exist on risks_array.

Comment: @rgomez oops. Yes it fails in this case. Change condition inside last loop to this `if(!isset($risks_array_count[$base_array[$i]]) || $base_array_count[$base_array[$i]] != $risks_array_count[$base_array[$i]]){`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by array_diff with some extra check. See here

```
$base_array = array(1,2,2,7);
$risks_array = array(1,2,2,3,4,5,6);

if(array_diff($base_array, $risks_array)) // false if $base_array has type of elemenes which $risk_array does not contain 
 echo "false"; //
else{
 // $risk_array has all type of elements of $base_array. now check for similar frequency
 $freq_cnt_base = array_count_values($base_array);
 $freq_cnt_risks = array_count_values($risks_array);
 $is_similar = "true";

 foreach($freq_cnt_base as $key => $val){
    if($freq_cnt_risks[$key] !== $freq_cnt_base[$key]){
        $is_similar = "false";
        break;
    }
 }
 echo $is_similar;
}
```